# How to display Ui-grid after data getting from services?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

This is my code

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  var today = new Date();
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    enableFiltering: false,
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
      $scope.gridApi.grid.registerRowsProcessor( $scope.singleFilter, 200 );
    },
    columnDefs: [
      { field: 'name' },
      { field: 'gender', cellFilter: 'mapGender' },
      { field: 'company' },
      { field: 'email' },
      { field: 'phone' },
      { field: 'age' },
      { field: 'mixedDate' }
    ]
  };

  $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/500_complex.json')
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
      $scope.gridOptions.data[0].age = -5;

      data.forEach( function addDates( row, index ){
        row.mixedDate = new Date();
        row.mixedDate.setDate(today.getDate() + ( index % 14 ) );
        row.gender = row.gender==='male' ? '1' : '2';
      });
    });
    
  $scope.filter = function() {
    $scope.gridApi.grid.refresh();
  };
    
  $scope.singleFilter = function( renderableRows ){
    var matcher = new RegExp($scope.filterValue);
    renderableRows.forEach( function( row ) {
      var match = false;
      [ 'name', 'company', 'email' ].forEach(function( field ){
        if ( row.entity[field].match(matcher) ){
          match = true;
        }
      });
      if ( !match ){
        row.visible = false;
      }
    });
    return renderableRows;
  };
}])
.filter('mapGender', function() {
  var genderHash = {
    1: 'male',
    2: 'female'
  };

  return function(input) {
    if (!input){
      return '';
    } else {
      return genderHash[input];
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input ng-model='filterValue'/><button ng-click='filter()'>Filter</button>
  <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
</div>


    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the above code first ui-grid structure display then after data will bind to the ui-grid, but i want to display entire grid with structure after loading data.
this is my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

A popular design is to show loading status when data is not yet loaded, to do so, you could add a `dataLoaded` flag to control when the grid is ready, set the flag as `true` in the success callback of `$http.get`. See the below:

```
$scope.dataLoaded = false;
$http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/500_complex.json').success(function(data) {
  // ...
  $scope.dataLoaded = true;
});
```

and in your template, it could be as:

```
<div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" ng-show="dataLoaded"></div>
<div ng-hide="dataLoaded">Loading...</div>
```

Comment: i have one more question ? i.e, how to hide column name on ui-grid

Comment: pls check if there is any option of ui-grid to do that :)

Comment: i will try number of options but not working like hideHeader: true and showHeader: false

Comment: do you want to hide a column or only the colum title? is there any option here? http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions.columnDef

Comment: i want to hide a column title only

Comment: then try to set `displayName` as blank (ie. empty space `""`) in the column definition.